# scrapy does not read settings from get_project_settings

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to run my crawler from a script, so I am using Crawler from scrapy.crawler (). This is the script I am running my crawler from (scrape_asd.py):

```
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from asd_scraping.spiders.asd_spider import AsdSpider

settings = get_project_settings()
crawler_run = Crawler(AsdSpider, settings)
crawler_run.crawl( 
    start_page = 0, 
    end_page = 10,
)
```

This script is located in the same directory as scrapy.cfg. My full (relevant) directory structure is listed below:

```
my_project\ 
    source\
        asd_scraping\
            scrape_asd.py
            scrapy.cfg
            asd_scraping\
                settings.py
                spiders\
                    asd_spider.py
```

My scrapy.cfg file looks like:

```
# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = asd_scraping.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = asd_scraping
```

get_project_settings() seems to work for everyone else with this setup, but for me the settings variable only has the default scrapy settings, i.e. none of the settings I have defined in settings.py get loaded. **How can I fix this?**

EDIT (Addition): When I run the scraper normally with scrapy crawl ... the settings get loaded properly

Comment: are you using an IDE?